# How to use EcmaScript 6 features in Ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework

I recently used the new Set data structure specification instead of an array where I didn't wanted any repeated values to be stored and it is working without problems, but I'm wondering I want to implement some of the new features such as `let`, `class` and  `const`.

I'm using also the crosswalk plugin in case this is relevant.

Can anyone tell me if I should avoid ES6 for the moment or if its okay to be used?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I actually googled about this myself earlier today and I found this tutorial: http://labs.encoded.io/2015/06/22/use-es6-with-ionic/

*StackOverflow encourages to not just use links as answers, so I'm just going to give my TL;DR, since this is not my own site and I don't want to be held accountable for c/p.*

Ionic uses Gulp, so install gulp-babel and gulp-plumber.

```
npm install --save-dev gulp-babel gulp-plumber
```

Add babel to `gulpfile.js` like so:

```
//...
var babel = require("gulp-babel");
var plumber = require("gulp-plumber");

var paths = {
  es6: ['./src/es6/*.js'],
  sass: ['./scss/**/*.scss']
};

gulp.task('default', ['babel', 'sass']);

gulp.task("babel", function () {
  return gulp.src(paths.es6)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("www/js"));
});

//...

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(paths.es6, ['babel']);
  gulp.watch(paths.sass, ['sass']);
});
//...
```

Edit `ionic.project`:

```
"gulpStartupTasks": [
    "babel",
    "sass",
    "watch"
 ],
```

For any more details consult the original link - and with this I also say thanks to the author of that blog post as it helped me too.

Comment: @user5148540: Great! I'm glad I helped!

Comment: @Nikola Thanks, it would be great if you could update your answer to match the link to the blog which was updated to include the es2015 preset. Without the preset, the file got copied from `/src/js` to `/www/js` but didn't get transpiled, just stayed as ES6

Comment: Sure, I can update without a problem. Can you just please tell me to which link? Because I can't seem to find the link to be different than it is now?

Comment: @Nikola, @ABCD.ca means the new module used `babel-preset-es2015` that has been updated in the same article. I also want to note that "gulpStartupTasks" does not seem to work for new CLI anymore, a task 'serve:before' is used now: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/999